# How to Mock Pulumi Resources in Go Unit Tests?

Tags: amazon-web-services, unit-testing, go, mocking, pulumi

I have a function that takes an input of an AWS OpenIdConnectProvider Pulumi Resource and creates a IAM Role with an AssumeRolePolicy attached that contains info from that OIDC provider.

**The Problem:** I am trying to write a test for this function and mock out a OIDC provider to feed in as input for the function call. I'm having trouble understanding how to properly mock this so that the test output shows what I expect, currently it appears that the mocked data isn't coming up like I'd expect.

It seems like I'm not using the mock correctly, but I went off the [example here](https://github.com/pulumi/examples/blob/master/testing-unit-go/main_test.go)

[Further Docs here](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/guides/testing/unit/)

```golang
package myPkg

import (
   "github.com/pulumi/pulumi-aws/sdk/v5/go/aws/iam"
   "github.com/pulumi/pulumi/sdk/v3/go/pulumi"
)

func CreateMyCustomRole(ctx *pulumi.Context, name string, oidcProvider *iam.OpenIdConnectProvider, opts ...pulumi.ResourceOption) (*iam.Role, error) {
    role := &iam.Role{}

    componentURN := fmt.Sprintf("%s-custom-role", name)

    err := ctx.RegisterComponentResource("pkg:aws:MyCustomRole", componentURN, role, opts...)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    url := oidc.Url.ApplyT(func(s string) string {
        return fmt.Sprint(strings.ReplaceAll(s, "https://", ""), ":sub")
    }).(pulumi.StringOutput)

    assumeRolePolicy := pulumi.Sprintf(`{
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [{
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": { "Federated": "%s" },
                "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
                "Condition": {
                    "StringEquals": {
                        "%s": [
                            "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:*",
                            "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:cluster-autoscaler"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }]
        }`, oidcProvider.Arn, url)

    roleURN := fmt.Sprintf("%s-custom-role", name)

    role, err = iam.NewRole(ctx, roleURN, &iam.RoleArgs{
            Name:             pulumi.String(roleURN),
            Description:      pulumi.String("Create Custom Role"),
            AssumeRolePolicy: assumeRolePolicy,
            Tags:             pulumi.ToStringMap(map[string]string{"project": "test"}),
        })
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return role, nil
}
```

```golang
package myPkg

import (
    "sync"
    "testing"

    "github.com/pulumi/pulumi-aws/sdk/v5/go/aws/iam"
    "github.com/pulumi/pulumi/sdk/v3/go/common/resource"
    "github.com/pulumi/pulumi/sdk/v3/go/pulumi"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

type mocks int

func (mocks) NewResource(args pulumi.MockResourceArgs) (string, resource.PropertyMap, error) {
    return args.Name + "_id", args.Inputs, nil
}

func (mocks) Call(args pulumi.MockCallArgs) (resource.PropertyMap, error) {
    outputs := map[string]interface{}{}
    if args.Token == "aws:iam/getOpenidConnectProvider:getOpenidConnectProvider" {
        outputs["arn"] = "arn:aws:iam::123:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/id/abc"
        outputs["id"] = "abc"
        outputs["url"] = "https://someurl"
    }
    return resource.NewPropertyMapFromMap(outputs), nil
}

func TestCreateMyCustomRole(t *testing.T) {
    err := pulumi.RunErr(func(ctx *pulumi.Context) error {

        // Gets the mocked OIDC provider to use as input for the CreateDefaultAutoscalerRole
        oidc, err := iam.GetOpenIdConnectProvider(ctx, "get-test-oidc-provider", pulumi.ID("abc"), &iam.OpenIdConnectProviderState{})
        assert.NoError(t, err)

        infra, err := CreateMyCustomRole(ctx, "role1", oidc})
        assert.NoError(t, err)

        var wg sync.WaitGroup
        wg.Add(1)

        // check 1: Assume Role Policy is formatted correctly
        pulumi.All(infra.URN(), infra.AssumeRolePolicy).ApplyT(func(all []interface{}) error {
            urn := all[0].(pulumi.URN)
            assumeRolePolicy := all[1].(string)

            assert.Equal(t, `{
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [{
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": { "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::123:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/id/abc" },
                "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
                "Condition": {
                    "StringEquals": {
                        "someurl:sub": [
                            "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:*",
                            "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:cluster-autoscaler"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }]
        }`, assumeRolePolicy)

            wg.Done()
            return nil
        })

        wg.Wait()
        return nil
    }, pulumi.WithMocks("project", "stack", mocks(0)))
    assert.NoError(t, err)
}

Output
```

```
                        Diff:
                        --- Expected
                        +++ Actual
                        @@ -4,3 +4,3 @@
                                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        -               "Principal": { "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::123:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/id/abc" },
                        +               "Principal": { "Federated": "" },
                                        "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
                        @@ -8,3 +8,3 @@
                                            "StringEquals": {
                        -                       "someurl:sub": [
                        +                       ":sub": [
                                                    "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:*",
        Test:           TestCreateMyCustomRole
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was using the `NewResource` wrong.

When `GetOpenIdConnectProvider` is called in the test function it goes to read a resource and create a new resource output which triggers the call to mocks.NewResource

The fix was to instead define an if statement for the resource type returned by the GetOpenIdConnectProvider `openIdConnectProvider`in the NewResource function call with the mocked outputs.

```golang
func (mocks) NewResource(args pulumi.MockResourceArgs) (string, resource.PropertyMap, error) {
    pulumi.Printf(args.TypeToken)
    outputs := args.Inputs.Mappable()
    if args.TypeToken == "aws:iam/openIdConnectProvider:OpenIdConnectProvider" {
        outputs["arn"] = "arn:aws:iam::123:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/id/abc"
        outputs["id"] = "abc"
        outputs["url"] = "https://someurl"
    }
    return args.Name + "_id", resource.NewPropertyMapFromMap(outputs), nil
}

func (mocks) Call(args pulumi.MockCallArgs) (resource.PropertyMap, error) {
    outputs := map[string]interface{}{}
    return resource.NewPropertyMapFromMap(outputs), nil
}
```

Is this below code snippet I changed the `assert` so that it fails to show what the diff now looks like with the changes made to NewResource above

```
Diff:
                            --- Expected
                            +++ Actual
                            @@ -8,3 +8,3 @@
                                                "StringEquals": {
                            -                       "b:sub": [
                            +                       "someurl:sub": [
                                                        "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:*",
```